# Application is working fine when run manually, but when it is run from the task scheduler it doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-task-scheduler, api, .net-core

That's it basically, when I run the app manually is able to find the files than it supposed to look for and work with them as it should, but when running from the task scheduler, even with my user, although the application run, it's unable to find the files to start processing them.

The application is a minimal API done in .Net 6, the server is a Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1 Build 7601.

Can somebody tell me what can be the thing stopping the app of finding the files to process them when running from a scheduled task?

Or at least how can i fix this?

I would like to being able to run that application from the task schedule as was intended to be.

Comment: Depending on your application, you may need to set Task Scheduler to "Run whether a user is logged on or not"  and also "Run with highest privileges"

Comment: It is running on the highest priviledges, and the "Run whether a user is logged on or not" it's already turned on.

The application is running, but is not finding the files that need to process, this files are, for instance, text files, pdfs, xmls, or similar.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to ensure files are not in a secured folder (program files )

Comment: They are not, not the target one, not the files of the program, i tell you this because for some reason is not reading the production config file either although is not in the same folder than the target files, this is when running from task, but it do read all the files (production config and target files) only when running manually.

Comment: Query the system from within your code to figure out what is going on.  Check who the current user is (from you process' point of view).  Query the file system to see what your process can see.  Write the results of your query to a text file/folder you have granted "everyone" access to.  This should only be a handful of lines in .net.  Just how I would approach this.  Since this is YOUR CODE that is running, you have tools that most people do not.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Sound like a plan, did you have any documentation related to that?, i can't install VS in those machines but if i'm understanding what you are telling me right, it means i can add it to the code and make the program tell me without VS, being such the case i'm very intrested in know how, it's the first time i heard about this but you get my attention, did you know where i can find more info about it?.

Comment: You are correct about you don't need VS.  Also.. start on your local machine and see if it works there.  As far as more info.. this is a programming concept, not an instruction.  Go into your program.cs.  [Query the current user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=net-6.0).  Use the Directory and File classes to query what you can see and or write to.  Use [this](https://zetcode.com/csharp/filestream/) to write out your file.  Querying the environment, checking permissions, and reading/writing text files is good learnin' :)

Comment: Well, doing that i notice than was than the application was being runned from Systems, i just change that to the folder where it supposed to be and presto, it works! thank you both but specially to you @SeñorCMasMas.